# How can I recreate this sound?

Tags: sound-design, sound, synthesizer

can you help me recreating this? (The sound starts 0:06 - 0:13)

https://www.facebook.com/kygoofficial/videos/1455768857819576/

Here's another example (The sound starts 0:00 - 0:05)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have anything like Sylenth1 this is realtively easy to make.

1st Osc: triangle wave with 4-8 polyphony. Add very slight detune.
2nd Osc: Sine wave with 2 polyphony, very slight detune.

Turn attack right down, turn sustain almost all the way down, turn up decay to taste, turn up release to about 0.2-0.5 seconds.

Now for the muted sound to really come to life add a Lowpass filter and place the peak at about 30hz (change this depending on the sound). turn up the resonance a little bit and then that should be all done. EQ and compress to taste.
[image]

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for helping me, I really appreciate it.
I'm not an expert of sylenth1, could you send me the fxp file?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not going to be near a computer with a DAW for the next few days. This sound is a very basic one to create however, It should be easy enough to make if you follow those instructions. Let me know if you have any problems however

Comment: Ok, no problem! I tried but nothing, I don't get that sound

Comment: can you screen shot what it is you are doing?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/67hpB.png

Comment: Did I miss something?@mark barton

Comment: You are using Serum. I said Sylenth 1

Comment: My apologise. When i was telling you how to create this sound I wasnt using any software, I was using memory. you will need to turn sustain and release all the way down. Decay should be pushed up to taste

Comment: Now I get a very similar sound, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like pizzicato strings or a muted nylon guitar to me.